# JoinDomainOrWorkgroup - Invalid method Parameter(s) 8004102F

Tags: delphi, wmi, ole, lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to write application to automate domain joining.
I use Lazarus v. 1.6.2 (Free Pascal) and wmi-delphi-code-creator v. 1.9.9.350
Here is the code:

```
function WMI_JoinDomainOrWorkgroup(const DomainName, Password, UserName, AccountOU, FJoinOptions :WideString):String;
const
  WbemServer        ='localhost';
  WbemNamespace     ='root\CIMV2';
  WbemUser          ='';
  WbemPassword      ='';
  WmiPath           ='Win32_ComputerSystem';
var
  FSWbemLocator   : OLEVariant;
  FWMIService     : OLEVariant;
  FWbemObjectSet  : OLEVariant;
  FOutParams      : OLEVariant;
  sValue          : string;
begin
  try
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
  except
    on E:EOleException do
        ShowMessage(Format('EOleException(CreateOleObject) %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        ShowMessage('Exception(CreateOleObject) ' + E.Classname + ':' + E.Message);
  end;

  try
    FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer(WbemServer, WbemNamespace, WbemUser, WbemPassword);
  except
    on E:EOleException do
        ShowMessage(Format('EOleException(ConnectServer) %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        ShowMessage('Exception(ConnectServer) ' + E.Classname + ':' + E.Message);
  end;

  try
    FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.Get(WmiPath);
  except
    on E:EOleException do
        ShowMessage(Format('EOleException(FWMIService.Get) %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        ShowMessage('Exception(FWMIService.Get) ' + E.Classname + ':' + E.Message);
  end;
  //####################################
  //#I have EOLEEXception in this Place#
  //####################################
  try
    FOutParams := FWbemObjectSet.JoinDomainOrWorkgroup(DomainName, Password, UserName, AccountOU, FJoinOptions); //<- I have EOLEEXception in this Place
  except
    on E:EOleException do
        ShowMessage(Format('EOleException(JoinDomainOrWorkgroup) %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        ShowMessage('Exception(JoinDomainOrWorkgroup) ' + E.Classname + ':' + E.Message);
  end;

  sValue:=FOutParams;
  Result := Format('ReturnValue %s',[sValue]);
end;

procedure TForm1.JoinPCToNewDomain;
var
  str_result: string;
begin
  str_result:='';

  try
    str_result := WMI_JoinDomainOrWorkgroup(WideString(edt_NewDomainName.Text),
                                            WideString(edt_PassNewDomain.Text),
                                            WideString(edt_NewDomainUser.Text),
                                            WideString(edt_NewDomainOU.Text), '3');
    Logger(str_result);
  except
    on E:EOleException do
        Logger(Format('EOleException %s %x', [E.Message,E.ErrorCode]));
    on E:Exception do
        Logger(E.Classname + ':' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

When I run application using this code I have the following error:

```
Invalid method Parameter(s) 8004102F
```

Please, help to solve this problem.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Probably you have to fill in the constants (wmipath, wbemuser..computer) with relevant data.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort 
Thank you for your comment! 
I've made some corrections to code. 
I've added try/except blocks and tried several variants of WmiPath:
If `WmiPath='winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\localhost\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name=localhost'`
or `WmiPath='Win32_ComputerSystem.Name=localhost'`
then I have EOleException (FWMIService.Get) and "Invalid object path 8004103A" error.
If `WmiPath='Win32_ComputerSystem'` then I have EOleException (JoinDomainOrWorkgroup) "Invalid method Parameter(s) 8004102F"
I've updated post

Comment: Well, then I'm out of options. I assume you have tried running as admin already?

Comment: Yep, I have admin rights when I run program. OS Windows 7 Professional SP1

Comment: I mean right click and then select run as administrator, just to be sure

Comment: It doesn't help